# exceptions across module boundaries in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, c++, module, exception

Item 62 of Sutter and Alexandrescu's book "C++ Coding Standards" is "Don’t allow exceptions to propagate across module boundaries."  Should we follow the same rule in C++/CLI?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to follow the [standard guidance for exception handling in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229014.aspx), provided you're working on the managed side.

When working on the native side of C++/CLI, it's a good idea to follow standard C++ guidance, which includes trying to prevent exceptions from crossing module boundaries.

Comment: Can you give a precise definition for what "working on the [managed/native] side" means in the context of the original question?

Comment: Well, when you're using C++/CLI, you can be writing code that will be executed using the CLR (managed), or that is native, compiled code.  The nice thing about C++/CLI is that the two can be mixed in a single exe or dll file.  When you're writing managed code (ref class ..., etc), you're basically using C++ to write .NET code.  In this case, follow .NET conventions.  If you're doing standard C++ in a C++/CLI project, you'll want to follow C++ conventions.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're .NET on both sides of the module boundary, exception propagation is safe--that's one of the points of using .NET.